# Joomla query with multiple where ( select multiple)

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I need to display a field in database for input multiple selects.

I tried this code:

```html
rowId= $cck->get('liaison_progression')->value; // id of your article/content
$value = explode( ',', $rowId);
$rowIdGr = implode("','", $value);
//echo $rowIdGr;
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('introtext' );
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' IN ('. $db->quote($rowIdGr).')');
//echo $query;
$db->setQuery($query);
$row3 = $db->loadObject();
```

but with this code I have this result:

Only the first object shows!
Do you have an idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you echo the query before it is executed and share the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try with using this method:

```
$row3 = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: It's same ! not change result

Answer (score 0):

Echo done :

```
SELECT introtext FROM `#__content` WHERE `id` IN ('435\',\'449')
```

and with

```
$row3 = $db->loadObjectList();
```

In the result I have the first object

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [introtext] => ::cck::478::/cck::
::config_semaine::12::/config_semaine::
  )

)
```

thank for your help